# Angular 2+ Sort list of data by parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am quite new to angular 2 and doing a simple blog with posts from database.  I use nodejs+express on backend to get data from db.I have posts component with posts in router-outlet from db and separate categories component with post categories also from db. What I want to achieve is to have the ability to filter posts by selected category by click on the category. Any ideas how it can be done?

node.js part of routes.js

```
app.get('/admin/posts', function (req, res) {
    sess = req.session;

    console.log('sess.userData', sess.userData);

    if (!sess.userData) {
        sess.userData = {
            id: [someId],
            email: [someEmail],
            name: [someName]
        };
    }

    if (sess.userData) {
        //get all posts when user checked
        Post.getAllPosts(function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return res.json(rows); 
        })

    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

//get posts by category, admin mode
app.get('/admin/posts/:category', function (req, res) {
    sess = req.session;

     if (!sess.userData) {
        sess.userData = {
            id: [someId],
            email: [someEmail],
            name: [someName]
        };
    }

    if (sess.userData) {
        //get all posts when user checked
        Post.findByCategory(req.params.category, function (err, rows, 
fields) {
            searchedCategory = req.params.category;
            existingCategory = rows[0].category;

            if (rows.length && existingCategory === searchedCategory) {
                //  res.json(rows[0].tags);
                return res.json(rows);
            } else
                return;
        })

    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

//get all posts categories
app.get('/admin/post_categories', function (req, res) {
    sess = req.session;

    if (!sess.userData) {
        sess.userData = {
            id: [someId],
            email: [someEmail],
            name: [someName]
        };
    }

    if (sess.userData) {

        Post.getAllCategories(function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return res.json(rows); 
        })

    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

post.component.html

```
  <article class="post-block">
 <section *ngFor="let post of posts" class="post">
     <article class="post__upper-block">
  <section class="post__img">
    <img class="post__img" src = "../../assets{{ post.titleImage }}" alt = 
  "post-img">
  </section>
  <section class="post__content">
    <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p class="post-text">{{ post.shortContent }}</p>
  </section>
  <section class="post__operations">
    <input type="button" value="Опубликован" class="post__btn post__btn--
 active">
    <input type="button" value="В работе" class="post__btn"> 
    <input type="button" value="Редактировать" class="post__btn"> 
  </section>
  </article>
  </section>
  </article>
```

post.service.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

  @Injectable()
  export class PostService {
  private _url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/posts";

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getPosts(){
   return this._http.get(this._url)
     .map(res => res.json())
  }

  }



post.component.ts



    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-post',
    templateUrl: './post.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss'],
    providers: [PostService]
    })

    export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: any[];
    categories: any[];


     constructor(private _postService: PostService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this._postService.getPosts()
        .subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
      }

    }
```

category.component.html

```
<article class="sidebar__categories">
  <h3 class="categories-header">Разделы</h3>

  <ul class="categories-ul">
    <li *ngFor="let category of categories" class="categories-ul__item">
            <a>{{ category.category }}</a>    
    </li>
  </ul>
 </article>
```

category.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

private _url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/post_categories";

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getCategories(){
console.log("get-categories service works");
  return this._http.get(this._url)
     .map(res => res.json())
}

}
```

category.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../services/category.service';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { PostComponent } from '../post/post.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-categories',
 templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss'],
 providers: [CategoryService, PostService]
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: any[];
  posts: any[];

 constructor(private _categoryService: CategoryService,
          private _postService: PostService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this._categoryService.getCategories()
        .subscribe(categories => this.categories = categories);

  }

}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CategoriesComponent } from 
 './components/categories/categories.component';
import { PostComponent } from './components/post/post.component';


 export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'authors-columns', component: AuthorsColumnsComponent },
{ path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
//   {path: 'admin/posts/:category', component: DashboardComponent},
{
    path: 'admin/dashboard/:category',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    resolve: {
        category: 'category'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom Pipe (filter) in the Angular, here is how you can go about it.

1) Angular 2 provides the PipeTransform Interface with the abstract transform method. So we have to implement this interface and override the transform method in our custom pipe
  (read more https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)
  2) Make use of the Angular Cli and generate the pipe.

```
ng g pipe category

Your category.ts file will look bit similar to 

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';
@Pipe({
  name: 'category'
})
export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let output: MyComponent[] = [];
    // args will get passed on click
    if(args!=='All') {
      for( var i=0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if(value[i].field_tags === args) {
          output.push(value[i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      output = value;
    }

    return output;
  }
}


3) Editing your post.component.html ( Check *ngFor)

  <article class="post-block">
 <section *ngFor="let post of posts | category:blogcategory" class="post">
     <article class="post__upper-block">
  <section class="post__img">
    <img class="post__img" src = "../../assets{{ post.titleImage }}" alt = 
  "post-img">
  </section>
  <section class="post__content">
    <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p class="post-text">{{ post.shortContent }}</p>
  </section>
  <section class="post__operations">
    <input type="button" value="Опубликован" class="post__btn post__btn--
 active">
    <input type="button" value="В работе" class="post__btn"> 
    <input type="button" value="Редактировать" class="post__btn"> 
  </section>
  </article>
  </section>
  </article>


4) Edit category.component.html to update (ngFor to update variable filter)

<article class="sidebar__categories">
  <h3 class="categories-header">Разделы</h3>

  <ul class="categories-ul">
    <li *ngFor="let category of categories" (click)="updateBlogCategory(filter)" class="categories-ul__item">
            <a>{{ category.category }}</a>    
    </li>
  </ul>
 </article>


 5) category.component.ts (added method updateBlogCategory)

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../services/category.service';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { PostComponent } from '../post/post.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-categories',
 templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss'],
 providers: [CategoryService, PostService]
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: any[];
  posts: any[];

 constructor(private _categoryService: CategoryService,
          private _postService: PostService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this._categoryService.getCategories()
        .subscribe(categories => this.categories = categories);

  }

  updateBlogCategory(stringCategory: string) {
    this.blogcategory = stringCategory;
  }


}
```

I hope this helps. If you can create plnkr it would be much easier to explain and edit.